# iOS Exception was thrown: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I have a problem. I am calling a method in another class. I call it before and it works perfect but I call back in another method near the end of the class and I have this error:

```
-(void)methodOne:(NSString*)myString
{
    mySecondClasss *second = [[mySecondClasss init] autorelease];
    [second doSomething:myString];
    /*
     more code
     */
}

-(void)methodTwo:(NSString*)myString
{
    mySecondClasss *second = [[mySecondClasss init] autorelease];
    [second doSomething:myString];
    /*
     more code
     */
}
```

In the second I'm getting this error:

Exception was thrown: -[mySecondClasss doSomething:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I don't understand why works once but not the second time. Any of you can give me some pointers of how can I fix this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What's the difference between methodOne and methodTwo? Just where you call them? Also, you should have an alloc before your init, is that a typo? The code you posted won't even compile.

Comment: Agree with rdelmar. More information on where you call these methods would be helpful.

Comment: The error clearly states that the `mySecondClasss` class has no method named `doSomething:`. Show the .h file for `mySecondClasss`.

Comment: The instance (*second) is not being allocated in all probability the first call succeeded because it was overlaying memory allocated to the  app, the second call failed because second = nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IOS 5 you have *ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)* which is automatically releasing the object correctly. Anyway you are not allocating the memory for the `mySecondClasss` class. Not sure why it even worked in the first method.

Instead of using

```
mySecondClasss *second = [[mySecondClasss init] autorelease];
```

Try using

```
mySecondClasss *second = [[mySecondClasss alloc] init];
```

Comment: Calling `[[mySecondClasss init] autorelease]` is clearly wrong but it also means that the OP is not using ARC. The code wouldn't even compile with ARC.

Comment: You need to allocate memory before instantiating a class with or without ARC.  In all probability, the first call worked because it was overlaying an existing part of your program, the second call failed because second = nil. Check this out when you debug.

Answer (score -3):

Are you sure that you are sending a string to the function? The error implies that the function is not getting a string.

For example:

```
[self methodOne:@"Properly formatted string"];
```

Comment: The error has absolutely nothing to do with how `methodOne:` or `methodTwo:` are called. It means there is no such method as `doSomething:` on the `mySecondClasss` class.